# Bootstrap - Popover does not activate on second click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using Bootstrap (with jQuery) to display a popover. My markup is:

```html
<div class="tooltip-div" id="TooltipDiv"
     onclick="onclickShowTooltip();"
     rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
     data-html="true"
     data-title="This is the tool tip.">

  <span class="ImageSpan">
    <img class="tooltipIcon" src="svg/Icons-28.svg"
               alt="tool tip icon" />
  </span>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript, I have:

```js
function onclickShowToolTip() {
  $('[data-toggle=popover]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $('.popover').css('bottom','100%')
  });
  $("#TooltipDiv").popover(
    {html: true,
     title: '',
     tigger: 'click',
     content: 'The meeting is secure.'});
  $("#TooltipDiv").popover('show');
}
```

The tool tip displays the first time I click on it. I then click outside the area and the tool tip disappears (as expected). But I click on the icon again and the tool tip does not display.

Why?

What setting/functionality am I missing?

Thanks for any ideas/help you can give.
Lori <*>

Comment: I'm guessing your function is messed up by the bootstrap built-in functions controlling tooltips on hover. Can you reproduce this on bootply?

Comment: You can reproduce the behaviour by uncommenting the original code in the fiddle mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you refer to `onclickShowTooltip()`, but your function is named `onclickShowToolTip`. Furthermore, the option "tigger" should be `trigger`. The reason why the popover only is shown once is, as I see it, the manual activation `popover("show")` last in the function.

I am not precisely sure why you want to do it this way. The great thing with popovers is that you can automate the whole process either by HTML attributes or by a `popover({})` initialisation. You can skip `onclickShowToolTip` and the `onclick` event completely, and simply have

```
$("#TooltipDiv").popover({
    html: true,
    title: '',
    trigger: 'click',
    content: 'The meeting is secure.'
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hdt0hy21/**

Comment: You are correct - a coworker found the "tigger" misspelling. The function names are another misspelling. I had to change the names before posting to avoid breaking company rules and didn't rename things in the post properly.
The reason for the "show" is because a) I need to set the text depending on other flags you don't see here and b) I found a problem where the tool tip does not show unless I do the manual popover("show"). I've been vectored off on something else so I need to go back and check the second click functionality again.
Thanks for the answer.